# CoreNLP for other languages like Arabic

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, arabic-support

I am using CoreNLP I have successfully executed it for English. I need to do the same for other languages like Arabic. May I please know how to train the system and use it for other languages?
please give me the steps in details

Answer (score 0):

CoreNLP already has some [Arabic](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#human-languages-supported) support -- you can see the grid of annotators supported for each language at: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html